# Make one ecdf that is colored by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like a single empirical cumulative density function (ECDF) that is color filled by a group. I can color the ECDF by group but there are different ECDFs for each group. How can I make a single ECDF that is colored by group, rather than having a seperate ECDF for each group?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

diamonds %>%
  slice_sample(prop = 0.01) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = price, fill = cut)) +
  stat_ecdf(geom = 'point', pad = F, shape = 21)
```

Below has separate `price` ECDFs for each `cut`. I would like for all of the `price` to be in one ECDF with the color of the point filled by `cut`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the desired function (`ecdf`) right within the mapping:

```
diamonds |>
  slice_sample(prop = 0.01) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = ecdf(price)(price)), shape = 21)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily calculate the `ecdf` on the whole dataset and then plot that with colors for each `cut`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>%
  slice_sample(prop = 0.01) %>%
  mutate(ecdf_price = ecdf(price)(price)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = price, y = ecdf_price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>